# GET API using Flutter From Nested Structure of JSON

Tags: flutter

so here I've just learned about parsing API using Flutter. So the problem is, how can i use this code below but use the API/JSON structure which I have included too?

Here's the code :

```
class TriedGetData extends StatelessWidget {
  final String apiUrl = "https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=15";
  Future<List<dynamic>> _fecthDataUsers() async {
    var result = await http.get(apiUrl);
    return json.decode(result.body)['data'];
  }
```

The json that i want to use :

```
{
  "x": {
    "y": {
      "a": "27 Jan 2022",
      "b": "20:20:02 WIB",
   }
}
```

and, I've already done like this. But still, it doesn't work,

```
Future<List<dynamic>> _fecthDataUsers() async {
    var result = await http.get(apiUrl);
    var data = json.decode(result.body)['x'];
    return data['y'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return data['y'];
```

try

```
return data[0];
```

as 'x' or data is a list and y is the 1st element in list , we should specify the index for it.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, that isn't a valid JSON format. If you're ever unsure, you can run it through [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com)

For the sake of this example, I turned it into a valid JSON object by simply adding a closing brace at the end:

```
{
    "x": {
        "y": {
            "a": "27 Jan 2022",
            "b": "20:20:02 WIB"
        }
    }
}
```

Then it should be a simple key mapping. You just missed the first level is all:

`data["x"]["y"]`

Put into practice, the end result looks something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {

  var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse("https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=5&page=1"));
  var response = await request.close();

  await for (var contents in response.transform(Utf8Decoder())) {
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(contents);
    var targetdata = jsondata["data"][0]["email"];
  }
}
```

The full decoded JSON data:

```
{
    page: 1,
    per_page: 5,
    total: 12,
    total_pages: 3,
    data: [{
                id: 1,
                email: george.bluth @reqres.in,
                first_name: George,
                last_name: Bluth,
                avatar: https: //reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg}, {id: 2, email: janet.weaver@reqres.in, first_name: Janet, last_name: Weaver, avatar: https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg}, {id: 3, email: emma.wong@reqres.in, first_name: Emma, last_name: Wong, avatar: https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg}, {id: 4, email: eve.holt@reqres.in, first_name: Eve, last_name: Holt, avatar: https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg}, {id: 5, email: charles.morris@reqres.in, first_name: Charles, last_name: Morris, avatar: https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg}], support: {url: https://reqres.in/#support-heading, text: To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!}}
```

The specific value you want to target `(targetdata)`:

`george.bluth@reqres.in`